# The [column] property of the [entity] entity was modified, but it won't be updated because the property is immutable

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

This has been asked before, but I haven't found any answers that work for my use case.
I've created a simplified toy example to explain my issue.
Imagine we have a `Customer` and `Purchase` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    protected Customer() {}

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Purchase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "item_name")
    private String itemName;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(updatable=false, insertable=false, name="first_name", referencedColumnName="first_name"),
        @JoinColumn(updatable=false, insertable=false, name="last_name", referencedColumnName="last_name")
    })
    Customer customer;
    public Customer getCustomer() { return customer; }
    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) { this.customer = customer; }

    public void setID(Long id) { this.id = id; }
    public Long getID() { return this.id; }

    protected Purchase() { }

    public Purchase(String itemName, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

As you can see, purchases are joined to customers using two columns: the first name of the customer, and last name (I know this is somewhat contrived since it would be better to join on customer id).
The issue is when I try to update an existing purchase. If the purchase details change, I create an entirely new purchase, set this new purchases's ID field, and save the new purchase which overwrites the old one since they have the same ID.

```
customerRepository.save(new Customer("firstName", "lastName"));
purchaseRepository.save(new Purchase("itemName", "firstName", "lastName"));

Purchase p1 = purchaseRepository.findAll().get(0);
Purchase p2 = new Purchase("updatedItemName", "firstName", "lastName");
p2.setID(p1.getID());
purchaseRepository.save(p2);
```

BUT, this always produces this warning:

```
2022-07-22 21:04:22.088  WARN 46139 --- [           main] o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister     : HHH000502: The [customer] property of the [com.example.accessingdatajpa.Purchase] entity was modified, but it won't be updated because the property is immutable.
```

I need help preventing this warning.

I know I could just update `p1` with `p2`'s data, but the issue is that in my actual code, purchases have a lot of fields and I want to avoid manually setting each one if possible.
If someone has a nicer solution where I update an old record based on a new one (without specifying the names of the columns to update), I'd love to see that solution.